# Java Jdk Installer won't start after UAC notification

Tags: java, windows-10

Problem installing java jdk-8u131-windows-x64. Tried disabling firewall & antivirus....After clicking YES on the UAC Notification nothing happens...it even does not give any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute jdk as administrator  ]
         or
Try to execute jdk in compatible mode as window 7
         or
If any of the above doesn't work either your jdk is corrupted  or your any other program is stopping to install java. So for that download a fresh new jdk and try to install 
else
Run windows in safe mode and then install

I m sure that any of the above method will work surely

Comment: Some windows file was corrupt....i tried re-installing the windows & it worked !!